# SyntaxError: invalid syntax after Cast a string to int

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have written a piece of code in python and when I let it run I get the following message:

```
File "port.py", line 229
    port = (int) a
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

since the code is a little bit too long, I give only the important part in the following section:

```
try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hle:t:p:cu:',
                                   ['help','listen','execute', 'target',
                                    'port', 'command', 'upload'])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print(str(err))
        usage()

    for o,a in opts:
        if o in ('-h', '--help'):
            usage()
        elif o in ('-l','--listen'):
            listen = True
        elif o in ('-e', '--execute'):
            execute = a
        elif o in ('-c','--commandshell'):
            command = True
        elif o in ('-u','--upload'):
            upload_destination = a
        elif o in ('-t','--target'):
            target = a
        elif o in ('-p','--port'):
            port = (int) a
        else:
            assert False,'Unhandled Option'
```

So, the **a** should be the port number which has string as type. So, I thought that I should cast it.

The version of python is 2.7.3.

I could not figure out why the error message appears. I hope somebody can help.

Best regards,

Comment: yes, I am new in python. Is there any way how I could convert it ?

Comment: Unless you are porting existing code that uses `getopt` to Python (and probably even then), you should use `argparse` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new `int` object from the string `a`, use

```
port = int(a)
```

Comment: when I do this, then I get the same message.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. You can't get `"port = (int) a"` in the error message if your code is `port = int(a)`.

Comment: Ah, ok...now I understand. Okay, thx. In the documentation which I have read, it was the same what you wrote. I changed the positions of the parantheses because normally I write my code in C. So, thank you.